# Intellij IDEA does not add end bracket

Tags: intellij-idea

Before, I used to be able to type `if (...) {` press enter, and it would add the end bracket like this

```
if (...) {
    
}
```

now I press enter, and it does not add the end bracket, instead it leaves me like this

```
if (...) {
```

How can I enable end bracket completion again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Enter | Insert pair '}'.